# How to use promises to return an array of objects that are being recursively edited in an express router in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, promise

I am trying to return an array of node objects, each of which has a unique label and array of children nodes, each identified by their unique label, for use in my frontend with a tree component (https://reactjsexample.com/a-simple-react-tree-menu-component/). A Category is a mongodb listing with a parent label, children array of children labels, their own unique label, and a number.

Running the createTreeJson function without a promise and printing treeData after a delay prints the correct result. I tried converting recursiveCat to return a promise and putting a .then after each recursiveCat call:

```
recursiveCat(node.nodes, category.label, indexC).then(() => resolve());
```

but that never finished the api call. I'm very new to promises and they are confusing to me despite some research.

```
router.get("/tree", (req, res) => {
var treeData= [];
createTreeJson(treeData).then(() => res.json(treeData));
function createTreeJson(treeData){
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        Category.find({ level: 0 }).then( categories => {
            categories.forEach((category) => {
              var node = {
                key: category.label,
                label: category.label,
                index: treeData.length,
                nodes: []
              }
              treeData.push(node);
              recursiveCat(node.nodes, category.label, treeData.length);
              resolve();
            });
          });
    })
}
function recursiveCat(nodes, parLabel, indexC){
  console.log("cat call")
    Category.find({ parent: parLabel }).then( categories => {
      categories.forEach((category) => {
        //console.log(category.children.length)
        var node = {
          key: category.label,
          label: category.label,
          index: indexC,
          nodes:  []
        }
        nodes.push(node);
        recursiveCat(node.nodes, category.label, indexC);
      })
    })
  }
})
```

Result:

```
[
    {
        "key": "Video Games",
        "label": "Video Games",
        "index": 0,
        "nodes": []
    },
    {
        "key": "Sports",
        "label": "Sports",
        "index": 1,
        "nodes": []
    }
]
```

Expected (generated from same code but without promises and printed after a delay and only sports shown as an example):

```
{ key: 'Sports',
  label: 'Sports',
  index: 1,
  nodes:
   [ { key: 'Basketball', label: 'Basketball', index: 2, nodes: [] },
     { key: 'Combat Sports',
       label: 'Combat Sports',
       index: 2,
       nodes: [] },
     { key: 'Soccer', label: 'Soccer', index: 2, nodes: [] },
     { key: 'Tennis', label: 'Tennis', index: 2, nodes: [] },
     { key: 'Track', label: 'Track', index: 2, nodes: [] },
     { key: 'Volleyball', label: 'Volleyball', index: 2, nodes: [] },
     { key: 'Football', label: 'Football', index: 2, nodes: [] },
     { key: 'Hockey', label: 'Hockey', index: 2, nodes: [] },
     { key: 'Golf', label: 'Golf', index: 2, nodes: [] },
     { key: 'Rugby', label: 'Rugby', index: 2, nodes: [] } ] }
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you! This is the first question I've asked so if I've asked incorrectly or am missing information let me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out the following code please.

```
var treeData= [];
createTreeJson(treeData).then((r) => res.json(r));
function createTreeJson(treeData){
    return Category.find({ level: 0 }).then( categories => {
        return Promise.all(
            categories.map(category => {
                var catArray = {
                    key: category.label,
                    label: category.label,
                    index: treeData.length,
                    nodes: []
                };
                return recursiveCat(node.nodes, category.label, treeData.length).then(
                    r => (catArray.nodes = r, catArray)
                );
            }
        ));
    });
}

function recursiveCat(nodes, parLabel, indexC){
    return Category.find({ parent: parLabel }).then( categories => {
        return Promise.all(categories.map((category) => {
            var catArray = {
                key: category.label,
                label: category.label,
                index: indexC,
                nodes:  []
            };
            return recursiveCat(node.nodes, category.label, indexC).then(
                r => (catArray.nodes = r, catArray)
            );
        }));
    })
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked. I'll need to look into Promise.all and .map.

Answer (score 1):

There is 2 problem in your code :

- `resolve()` is like a `return`, you need to put something in. You should write :

  `resolve(recursiveCat(node.nodes, category.label, treeData.length))`
- Your recursive function doesn't return anything. I think it should look more like that :

```js
function recursiveCat(nodes, parLabel, indexC){
  console.log("cat call");
    Category.find({ parent: parLabel }).then( categories => {
      categories.forEach((category) => {
        var self_node = recursiveCat(node.nodes, category.label, indexC);
        var node = {
          key: category.label,
          label: category.label,
          index: indexC,
          nodes:  self_node
        }
        nodes.push(node);
        
        
      });
      return nodes;
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I got it working with pindev's solution, but I'll get yours to work too just to better my understanding of how it works.